# Sleep issues on my Razer Blade Stealth on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, suspend

I have decided to make the leap from Windows to Linux, but I have been having one issue. Whenever I close the lid of my laptop, it goes into sleep mode, and when I open the lid, it comes back awake. My issue is, that 30 seconds or a minute into use, it goes automatically into sleep for NO reason and I don't know why it does this. I then have to press the power button to to wake it up, but then it just repeats and I have to completely power off to fix it.

Any solutions? I can provide info as needed, provided you tell me how to get that info.

Comment: I'm having the same issues on Ubuntu 16.10. I haven't tried this yet but apparently the solution to this is adding '“button.lid_init_state=open” to the grub boot parameters and update grub.' see here https://blogs.aerys.in/jeanmarc-leroux/2017/02/07/ubuntu-on-the-razer-blade-stealth-late-2016/

Comment: Please accept the answer below which solves your question by clicking the green check mark beside it.

Answer (score 6):

Editing the GRUB boot parameters as suggested did the job for me (on 16.10).

1. Open a terminal and run:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   which will open the gedit text editor.
2. Search for the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` (which was empty in my case) and change it to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="button.lid_init_state=open"
   ```
3. Save and close gedit.
4. Update GRUB with the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Restart.

Comment: Thank you so much! Only thing I would say, is that it was not GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, I had to put it under GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. Thank you, I can finally close my laptop lid!

Comment: @ZVNexus You may want edit both of these as the ~DEFAULT line is used to add kernel init arguments for newly installed kernel versions. Otherwise these arguments may get dropped whenever a system update installs a new kernel.
BTW. I've got Razer Blade Stealth running Ubuntu 16.04 too and I'm facing the same issue. I wonder did it happen to you that laptop was going into sleep like mode (green led flashing with screen off) instead (re)booting? No way to wake it up, only cold off by holding the power button for 5 sec to get it out of such state.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the nvidia drivers. See [NVidia CUDA Installation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#)