# Ubuntu 19.10 on Razer Blade - After wake up laptop automatically suspends

Tags: suspend, 19.10

Recently I've got a [Razer Blade 15](https://www.razer.com/gaming-laptops/razer-blade/shop#rtx2060--fhd-144hz-9thgen--512gb-25slot-quartz) system (Mid 2019), installed Ubuntu 19.10 and everything works fine except one thing.

When I suspend the laptop (lock + closing the lid), I get some problems after waking it up.

First thing - touchpad is not working. I've found [workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968790/how-to-run-sudo-sh-file-after-wakeup-touchpad-disabled-after-upgrading-to-ubu) - touchpad works, but there is another bigger problem. After one minute or so computer automatically suspends again. Doesn't matter if I am doing anything or not.

Do you have any idea what can cause this problem? Currently I used "Tweaks" to turn off suspending on lid closing, but that's temporary solution.

EDIT: After more testing - problem only occurs when suspend is triggered by closing the lid. Auto suspend after time and suspending with power button doesnt cause the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Editing the GRUB boot parameters as suggested in [Sleep issues on my Razer Blade Stealth. 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894785/sleep-issues-on-my-razer-blade-stealth-16-04-lts) fixed this for me (on 20.04).

1. Open a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Change the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` to include the parameter `button.lid_init_state=open`, so for example it may read:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="button.lid_init_state=open"
   ```

   Existing parameters such as `quiet` `splash` etc can be left as they are. Parameters should be separated by spaces within the double quotes.
3. Update GRUB with the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Restart.